# Validating a JSON generated dropdown with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, html, json, magento, jquery-validate

Trying to validate a dropdown using jQuery Validate. The form data is generated using JSON. I can add a "required" to input fields but it seems as if its not possible doing this with a dropdown. Below is what I have and it does not seem to work.

Is there a way to add an action to make sure the user selects an option?

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Starting Calander Options",
        "name": "overlay2",
        "type": "select",
        "id": "calander",
        "options": {
            "": "none",
            "calendar13": "January 2015",
            "calendar14": "February 2015",
            "calendar15": "March 2015",
            "calendar16": "April 2015",
            "calendar17": "May 2015",
            "calendar18": "June 2015",
            "calendar19": "July 2015",
            "calendar20": "August 2015",
            "calendar21": "September 2015",
            "calendar22": "October 2015",
            "calendar23": "November 2015",
            "calendar24": "December 2015"
        }
    },
]
```

Jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqnew = jQuery.noConflict();

    jqnew("#stringForm").validate({
        messages: {
            calander: {
                required: "Please select an option from the list, if none are appropriate please select 'Other'",
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="leftArea">
    <form id="stringForm"> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" id="id"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="new-profile" name="newprofile" value="yes"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="text-name" name="text_name" value=""/>
    </form>

    <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml("customization_radio") ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChild("customization_radio") -> setProduct($product)->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Also as a note, I am on the Magento framework 7

Comment: Your framework, or lack of framework, has absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript.  The ***rendered*** HTML of the `select` element is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Somehow I missed the "jQuery Validate" reference in the original question.  I'll go ahead and leave my answer though, as a validation approach for people searching for a simple jQuery validation (or flexible to either approach), and finding this question.

---

The jQuery check that you will want to do is a simple check of the dropdown's value using the `.val()` method.

If you want to make sure that the user has selected a value, check to make sure that the current value of the dropdown does not equal the value of the default option (i.e., the value set by `"": "none",`):

```
if ($("#DROPDOWN_ID_VAL").val() !== "") {
    // logic for when it passes validation
}
else {
    // logic for when it DOES NOT pass validation
}
```

Comment: As per his usage of the `.validate()` method and inclusion of the `jquery.validate.js` file, the OP is asking about how to use the jQuery Validate plugin, not write a custom validation script from scratch.

Comment: @Sparky - Wow . . . I'm not sure how I missed that.  Gonna chalk it up to being late on a Friday afternoon and having a head cold.   :D  I've added in an edit, but left my answer, in case it could be helpful to someone else who might land here after searching for "validating dropdown jQuery".   :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON...

```
"caption": "Starting Calander Options",
"name": "overlay2",
"type": "select",
"id": "calander",
"options": {
    "": "none",
    "calendar13": "January 2015",
    ....
}
```

Your jQuery...

```
jqnew("#stringForm").validate({
    messages: {
        calander: {
            required: "Please select an option from the list, if none are appropriate please select 'Other'",
        },
    }
});
```

You have two critical issues here that are preventing the `required` validation from working...

1. Validation rules can only be declared within the `.validate()` method *using the `name` attribute, not the `id`*.  You are using `calander` within the `.validate()` method, but as per your JSON, `calander` is the `id` of your `select`.  Within this method you should be using `overlay2`, which is what you seem to have defined as the `name` of your `select`.  *(FWIW, you've also misspelled "calendar" as "calander" for your `id`.)*
2. You have not declared any rules at all within `.validate()`.  Rules are declared with the `rules` option, and custom messages are declared with the `messages` option.  You cannot declare a rule within `messages` and vice-versa.

Otherwise, as long as the first `option` within your `select` contains `value=""`, which you already have, the `required` rule will work as expected.

You should also enclose your jQuery code within a DOM ready event handler to ensure the HTML is fully constructed before the method is called.

**Working Code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jqnew) { // ensure DOM is ready

        jqnew("#stringForm").validate({
            rules: {         // <- declare your rules
                overlay2: {  // <- the NAME attribute
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {      // <- define your custom messages
                overlay2: {  // <- the NAME attribute
                    required: "Please select an option from the list, if none are appropriate please select 'Other'"
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4195L9e8/**